# Error when using partial view in nopcommerce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, nopcommerce

I am using nopcommerce 2.2 & trying to use the partial view `ProductVariant_SKU_Man_Stock` in the `_Productbox.cshtml` but it comes up with the error:
The model item passed into the dictionary is of type

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.ProductModel+ProductVariantModel]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.ProductModel+ProductVariantModel'.

Below is the `_Productbox.cshtml`:

```
@model Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.ProductModel
<div class="product-item">
<h2 class="product-title">
@Model.Name
</h2>
<div class="description">
      @Html.Partial("_ProductVariant_SKU_Man_Stock",Model.ProductVariantModels)
    @Html.Raw(Model.FullDescription) <br />
    @Model.Size
</div>
<div class="add-info">
    <div class="prices">
        @Html.Partial("_ProductPrice", Model.ProductPrice)
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
       @* <input type="button" value="@T("Products.Details")" class="productlistproductdetailbutton" onclick="setLocation('@Url.RouteUrl("Product", new { productId = Model.Id, SeName = Model.SeName })')" />
*@        @if (!Model.ProductPrice.DisableBuyButton)
        {
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="@T("ShoppingCart.AddToCart")" class="productlistaddtocartbutton" onclick="setLocation('@(@Url.RouteUrl("AddProductToCart", new { productId = Model.Id }))')" />
        }
     </div>
     </div>
     </div>
```

Is there any other way of doing it coz i need some fields within that partial view to display in this view.

productmodel.cs:

```
 public class ProductModel : BaseNopEntityModel
{
    public ProductModel()
    {
        ProductPrice = new ProductPriceModel();
       // ProductSku = new ProductSkuModel();
        DefaultPictureModel = new PictureModel();
        PictureModels = new List<PictureModel>();
        ProductVariantModels = new List<ProductVariantModel>();
        SpecificationAttributeModels = new List<ProductSpecificationModel>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string ShortDescription { get; set; }

    public string FullDescription { get; set; }

    public string ProductTemplateViewPath { get; set; }

    public string MetaKeywords { get; set; }

    public string MetaDescription { get; set; }

    public string MetaTitle { get; set; }

    public string SeName { get; set; }
    public string Size { get; set; }
    public ProductPriceModel ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public bool DefaultPictureZoomEnabled { get; set; }
    public PictureModel DefaultPictureModel { get; set; }
    public IList<PictureModel> PictureModels { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductVariantModel> ProductVariantModels { get; set; }
    public IList<ProductSpecificationModel> SpecificationAttributeModels { get; set; }
    public class ProductVariantModel : BaseNopEntityModel
    {
        public ProductVariantModel()
        {
            ProductSku = new ProductSkuModel();
            GiftCard = new GiftCardModel();
            ProductVariantPrice = new ProductVariantPriceModel();
            PictureModel = new PictureModel();
            AddToCart = new AddToCartModel();
            ProductVariantAttributes = new List<ProductVariantAttributeModel>();
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public bool ShowSku { get; set; }

        public string Sku { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public bool ShowManufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }

        public string ManufacturerPartNumber { get; set; }

        public string DownloadSampleUrl { get; set; }

        public GiftCardModel GiftCard { get; set; }

        public string StockAvailablity { get; set; }

        public ProductVariantPriceModel ProductVariantPrice { get; set; }

        public AddToCartModel AddToCart { get; set; }

        public PictureModel PictureModel { get; set; }
        public ProductSkuModel ProductSku { get; set; }

        public IList<ProductVariantAttributeModel> ProductVariantAttributes { get; set; }
        public class ProductVariantPriceModel : BaseNopModel
        {
            public string OldPrice { get; set; }

            public string Price { get; set; }
            public string PriceWithDiscount { get; set; }

            public decimal PriceValue { get; set; }
            public decimal PriceWithDiscountValue { get; set; }

            public bool CustomerEntersPrice { get; set; }

            public bool CallForPrice { get; set; }

            public int ProductVariantId { get; set; }

            public bool HidePrices { get; set; }

            public bool DynamicPriceUpdate { get; set; }
        }
        public class ProductSkuModel : BaseNopModel
        {


            public string Sku { get; set; }

            public bool ShowSku { get; set; }
        }
```

Want to use this partial view :

```
@model Nop.Web.Models.Catalog.ProductModel.ProductVariantModel
@if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.StockAvailablity))
{
    <div class="stock">

        @Model.StockAvailablity
    </div>
 }
<div class="clear">
</div>
@if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.Sku) && Model.ShowSku)
{
    <div class="sku">

        @Model.Sku
    </div>
}
<div class="clear">
</div>
@if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ManufacturerPartNumber) && Model.ShowManufacturerPartNumber)
{
    <div class="manufacturerpartnumber">

        @Model.ManufacturerPartNumber
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative way in which you can bring the attributes like stock quantity in `ProductVariant_SKU_Man_Stock` into the `_Productbox.cshtml`,without using partial view.

The way is as follows:

Add the following set of code
In `Productmodel.cs`,there is a nested class called

```
public class ProductPriceModel : BaseNopModel
{
  //here declare stockquantity 
   public int stockqty { get; set; }
}
```

In `catalogcontroller.cs`,

there is a function called

```
private ProductModel.ProductPriceModel PrepareProductPriceModel(Product product)
{ 
  //ADD THIS CODE BELOW
  model.stockqty=productvariants[0].StockQuantity;
}
```

In `_Productbox.cshtml` add

```
@if (Model.ProductPrice.stockqty <= 0)
{
   <div class="innerrtcarts"> 
    insert out of stock message or image
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The _ProductVariant_SKU_Man_Stock view is expected a single ProductVariantModel and you are giving it a list of them.  If you know you will only have one Variant then just change that line to

```
@Html.Partial("_ProductVariant_SKU_Man_Stock",Model.ProductVariantModels.First())
```